# Data Base trigger after table create on mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I got a data base trigger after table create.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  tr_Timestamps_TableTriggersCreation
ON DATABASE
AFTER CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME
    DECLARE @schemaName SYSNAME = NULL
    DECLARE @totalRows INT = 0;

    SELECT @tableName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','SYSNAME') 

    SELECT TOP 1 @schemaName = s.name
    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE t.name = @tableName
    AND c.name = 'ID'

    IF (@schemaName != '')
    BEGIN
        EXEC u_general.sp_Timestamps_TriggerForTableCreation @tableName, @schemaName, 'I'
        EXEC u_general.sp_Timestamps_TriggerForTableCreation @tableName, @schemaName, 'U'
    END
```

The idea behind it is to create 2 trigger for each table which is being created on that database.

My problem is as follow,

When someone uses the MSSQL 'editor' and uses the 'Design' option instead of writing a script for making changes such as marking a column for 'Allow Null or not', change the data type etc... 
My Data base trigger counts it as a new table creation and launches the procedure which create the triggers for that table.
The end result is that it tries to create those triggers again and i get an error message that those triggers already exist.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [u_general].[sp_Timestamps_TriggerForTableCreation] ( @tableName sysname, @schemaName sysname, @actionType char(1))
AS


   DECLARE @TrigerName NVARCHAR(50)
   DECLARE @AfterActionName NVARCHAR(50)

   IF @actionType = 'I'
   BEGIN
        SET @TrigerName = 'tr_Timestamps_CaptureAfterInsert_' + @tableName
        SET @AfterActionName = 'INSERT'
   END
   ELSE -- 'U'
   BEGIN
        SET @TrigerName = 'tr_Timestamps_CaptureAfterUpdate_' + @tableName
        SET @AfterActionName = 'UPDATE'
   END

 DECLARE @SQLCommand nvarchar(max)= 
'CREATE TRIGGER ' + @TrigerName +'
ON ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName  +
' AFTER '+ @AfterActionName +'
AS
    DECLARE @auditBody XML
    DECLARE @RowID int

    SELECT @RowID = INSERTED.ID FROM INSERTED
    SELECT @auditBody = 
        ''<Timestamps_Request>
            <DataBaseName>'' + DB_NAME() + ''</DataBaseName>
            <SchemaName>'' + ''' + @schemaName + ''' + ''</SchemaName>
            <TableName>'' + ''' + @tableName + '''+ ''</TableName>
            <RowID>'' + CAST(@RowID AS NVARCHAR(30)) + ''</RowID>
            <Action>'' + '''+@actionType+''' + ''</Action>
        </Timestamps_Request>''

    EXEC u_general.sp_Timestamps_SendBrokerMessage @FromService = ''Timestamps_RequestService'',
    @ToService   = ''Timestamps_ProcessingService'',
    @Contract    = ''Timestamps_Contract'',
    @MessageType = ''Timestamps_Request'',
    @MessageBody = @auditBody  ';

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQLCommand
```

My question is,

What can i do to make sure that it wont happen every time someone decides to use the designer for 'altering' a table?

P.S. From my understanding it has something to do with the SSMS (causes drop and create? ) and the way it works, and this is why i dont have this issue while using a script to modify the table instead of the MSSQL designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Quick Note before direct answer.*

Use [DDL Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx) with `CREATE_TABLE` and Confirm you Don't using `Alter_TABLE` within your Trigger definitions, because `CREATE_TABLE` and `Alter_TABLE`  is totally separated events.

Follow the next Demo for more Details.

**Demo:-**

```
Create table table1 (col1 int, col2 nvarchar(10) not null )
go

Create TRIGGER NoCreateNewTables ON DATABASE 
    FOR  CREATE_TABLE
AS 

Print 'Prevent Table Creation'
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END    

GO
```

Lets `Alter` `Table1` Via next:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN col2 nvarchar(10) NULL
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Lets `Create` new table `Table2` Via next:

```
Create table table2 (col1 int, col2 nvarchar(10) not null )
```

**Result:-**

[image]

### What about SSMS

*The direct answer starts here*

SQL Server drops and recreates the tables while using `SSMS` designer in some cases:

Common cases:-

- Add a new column.
- Change the Allow Nulls setting for a column.
- Change the column order in the table.
- Change the column data type.

**After some investigation** , I noticed the `Object_Name` that altered via `SSMS` designer Starts with `Tmp_`.

so according to this info we can prevent alter table via `SSMS` designer by Create Trigger for Preventing altering table from SSMS while table recreated.

**Demo:-**

```
/* Create Trigger for Preventing altering table Via SSMS while table recreated */
Create TRIGGER TrgPreventAlterTableIfTableRecreatedViaSSMSDesign ON DATABASE 
    FOR  CREATE_TABLE
AS 

BEGIN
DECLARE
            @eventInfo XML,
            @ObjectName varchar(100)
SET
            @eventInfo = EVENTDATA()

select @ObjectName = CONVERT(SYSNAME, @eventInfo.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)'))

if (Left(@ObjectName,3) = 'Tmp')
begin
exec sp_addmessage 50001, 16,   
    N'Cannot modify Table Via SSMS, use [Alter Table] Code instead';

RAISERROR(50001,16,1)

exec sp_dropmessage 50001

rollback;

end
END
```

Now Try alter `Table1` Via `SSMS` designer from `NULL` to `NOT NULL`

The next pop messages will be raised:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It works but the problem is if someone is going to want to create a table named Tmp_YYYZZZ